Can a necessary thing explain another necessary thing?
If everything is necessary, what exactly counts as an explanation? I was watching an interesting debate between Graham Oppy and Rob Koons (atheist and theist philosophers. Link here.
Graham makes the point that if something is necessary, it needs no further explanation apart from its necessity. He also makes the further point that something that is necessary can imply something else that is necessary, but that doesn’t explain the necessity of either.
For example, if the axioms of math are necessary, then this implies that 2 + 2 = 4. However, he would argue that the axioms of math don’t explain 2 + 2 = 4. Rather, 2 + 2 = 4 is merely one of the many things that are implied by those axioms: we just don’t always spell them out.
Would this be accurate? I tend to agree but I’m not sure. Koons disagrees in the video.

If any account of explanation is merely a pragmatic tool then Oppy's position is sound, yet note in the basic normal modal logic K the proposition □p→p doesn't hold in general, therefore though the axiomatized necessity of K implies another necessity □(¬□(□p→p)) via its necessary necessitation rule without any further explanation, the truth of p cannot be implied by the mere necessity of p, that is to say, even the necessity of p is explained outside, the truth of p still cannot be attained. Yet once this implication is necessary, then another necessity arises per Löb's theorem □(□p→p)→□p...

I love watching discussions with Graham Oppy and theist philosophers - I always come away appreciating both sides more.
Your question is about necessity but really it is getting at the nature of explanation.

To address your immediate question

Can a necessary thing explain another necessary thing?

Yes -- if □A and if in world w we have A →B then we have B being true in w. If we assume the standard K (Kripke) modal logic and if we make the stronger assumption that □(A → B) then we have

□(A → B) → (□A → □B) (from K)
□A 
∴ □B

I think that is what Graham is getting at (I'm pretty sure his modal logic skills are pretty sharp ;).
You can call the above a "domino necessitation" -- in classical determinism, it was indeed thought God was the prime necessary entity and the rest was necessary by something like the above modal implication.

Getting at the more interesting question behind the question is when can we call something satisfyingly explained (lets call this s'plained ;-). In general, for B to be s'plained, we need some kind of implication that shows why B must be true (at least in our world w).
So, we can model s'plaining as implication and then ask about antecedents. If A always implies B, and A is necessary, then B is necessary. But why is A necessary? This is where we see the limits of s'plaining in general. Just like a little child, we can always push for a further why without end. The problem lies in our desire for causal/implication-based explanations, which make us feel like we understand things, and that gives us a feeling of control in a world that so often feels out of our control and understanding.
However, this cannot go on forever. At some point s'plaining must stop. This stopping point will be brute. This is the sophisticated, philosophical version of "Because it just is!!" that exasperated parents give to their curious children. And just like the kids, we are not satisfied by that result.  But it may be correct nonetheless.
The formal description of this is the Principle of Sufficient Reason (PSR) :

The Principle of Sufficient Reason is a powerful and controversial philosophical principle stipulating that everything must have a reason, cause, or ground. This simple demand for thoroughgoing intelligibility yields some of the boldest and most challenging theses in the history of philosophy.

(Source: Melamed, Yitzhak Y. and Martin Lin, "Principle of Sufficient Reason", The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy (Summer 2023 Edition), Edward N. Zalta & Uri Nodelman (eds.), URL = https://plato.stanford.edu/archives/sum2023/entries/sufficient-reason/.)
In general, the PSR is a very good principle to go by to prevent one from prematurely ending an investigation. One could argue that science is based the application of PSR but a restricted form that we could call the Principle of Sufficient Naturalistic Reason (PSNR) - given methodological naturalism forms the core of science.
However, just because a principle is widely useful and correct doesn't mean it's always useful and correct. Like abduction, its most uncontroversial application is in the exploratory stage of an inquiry (e.g., generating hypotheses), not forcing conclusions. "Inference to the best explanation", while sounding lovely, requires a lot of unpacking -- the process of which will render it far less agreeable ;)
So if we cannot PSR/Abduct ourselves to final truth, but must ultimately rest our case on some brute facts/necessities, what can we do to make progress?
At this stage, you need to move away from explanations qua explanations and instead focus on explanations as an expression of a particular worldview from which they emanate. For Graham Oppy, this specifically is Naturalism vs Theism/Supernaturalism.
You compare worldviews based on their explanatory power, how many commitments you are forced to make (these are the brute facts you need to accept), and how sound do those commitments appear in light of the evidence or alternative world views.

This may be unsatisfying because we want a knock-down argument to settle things, but ultimately it boils down to what commitments we feel (<-- note emotional criteria, not logical) most comfortable making. And even amongst smart, rational people, these feelings will be different.


If everything is necessary, what exactly counts as an explanation?

But not everything is necessary.
For example, if it rains, it is not necessarily the case that I am wet.
So, what is said to be necessary is what follows necessarily from the premises.
Once you accept the premises, the logical conclusion becomes necessary  . . but only from your own perspective.

Are you saying logic is subjective in the last sentence?

@PW_246 No, I didn't say that. Logic is undeniably subjective, though. And verifiably objective as well. But I don't think you understand what we all mean by "objective". It is because logic is objective that the so-wrongly called "mathematical logic" is false.
